# cells property leaks memory on Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging, memory-leaks, cross-browser, appendchild

Neither the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh453026.aspx) nor [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-67349879) mention the leak.

It happens on dynamically created rows. This is an issue for us as we have a one-page web application with tables regularly updated via ajax, and eventually iexplore consumes all the memory and Windows dies.

To reproduce:

```
function process() {
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  var cell = document.createElement('td');
  var text = document.createTextNode();
  
  // doesn't matter order of these lines:
  row.appendChild(cell);
  cell.appendChild(text);
  
  // this leaks on IE8/9:
  var x = row.cells;
  
  // this alternative doesn't:
  //var x = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
  
  setTimeout(process, 10);
}

process();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5wzW2/1/
(The jsfiddle site doesn't work on IE8, hence posting the code above).

Watch Mem Usage for iexplore go up about a MB every minute in Task Manager. Doesn't in FF18/Chrome24.

Any ideas why, or what best to do about it?

[Microsoft's bug reporting page](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE) appears to be broken. My workaround is to replace `.cells` with `.getElementsByTagName("td")`, e.g. in the [tablesorter](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There are [circular references](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/dd361842) to the `row` and `cell` DOM objects because they refer to themselves while they are not in the document tree:

```
var row = document.createElement('tr');
row.appendChild(cell);
```

In addition, the call to the `cells` property returns an [IHTMLElementCollection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/aa741775)

Which has a memory leak bug in IE10:

- [Memory leak when you use an enumerator object in an application for Internet Explorer 10](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2880281)